# Can someone explain difference between HttpResponse and HttpResponseRedirect in Django?

Tags: django-views

I am not getting the difference between HttpResponse n HttpResponseRedirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpResponseRedirect` is meant to send a 3xx HTTP code and redirect
to another URL (that is, the response is a redirect header).
It is actually a subclass of `HttpResponse`, and can be used as a shortcut
for redirects.

`HttpResponse`, on the other hand is the main response object, where you can
set headers / body, etc (and is what you usually use for sending a rendered
template and so on -- ok, render_to_response also does that, but it is a
shortcut function).